# Page buttons don't work in Google chart table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I try to enable page buttons in Google Chart Table, but it doesn't work:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#table
Change last line to: visualization.draw(data, {page: 'enabled', pageSize: 1});

After that, buttons are visible, but don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for the page option is actually 'disable'(default) or 'enable'.
If you change the last line to

```
visualization.draw(data, {page: 'enable', pageSize: 1});
```

the paging should work.